# Meaning of the word " reaffirmation" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

It is from [Crash Course US history](https://youtu.be/GzTrKccmj_I). It is at around 4 minute and 31 second.

> In his first Gettysburg address,Abrham Linkoln fostered the idea that the Civil War was kind of second American Revolution or a culmination and **reaffirmation** of the first one.

As it is defined in the [Machmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/reaffirm) the word means to state something officially again, and it doesn't seem to fit the context.

Comment: reaffirmation of the American Revolution doesn't fit the context?

Comment: I thought so, but now...

Comment: We spell Lincoln with a C, not a K.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the Oxford English Dictionary, *reaffirm* means:

> 1. verb State again strongly.
>
> *‘the prime minister reaffirmed his commitment to the agreement’*
>
> 1.1 Confirm the validity of (something previously established)

To *affirm* something is to state or demonstrate a point or a fact as definitely true. "The mutual defence treaty **affirms** the bond of friendship between these countries". "Marriage vows **affirm** the couple's commitment to one another".

To **reaffirm** something is to repeat a point or fact that has already been affirmed, in order to show ongoing commitment to it. "This new trade treaty **reaffirms** the bond of friendship between these countries". "Having children together **reaffirms** the couple's commitment to one another".

The idea is that since the American Civil War was fought over the rights of individuals, it is being seen as similar to the original American Revolution. Once again, American settlers fought to establish and maintain individual rights and freedoms, and to end a perceived injustice.

Comment: But I cannot get what the verb "reaffirm" means there itself

Comment: Edited to clarify. It's based around *affirm*, meaning to state something strongly and definitely as true. *Reaffirm* is simply to repeat something that has already been affirmed.